# can we create VG on a docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, centos6.5, dockerhub

i need to know how we can creat a VG(Volume group) on a docker container because when i try pvscan in a centos container i have this result:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-14:~$ sudo docker run -t -i centos-6-5 /bin/bash

bash-4.1# pvscan
```

No matching physical volumes found

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

docker containers are more about running applications than worrying about system stuff such as volume groups.

All your applications need to know is where to access/save files. They should not care if that location is on the filesystem itself or if it is a mount point on the network or whatever.

Given those facts, I'm not sure Docker is the right tool for whatever you want to do with volumes groups.